# Are there mention of Samavatsaras in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

Does Mahabharata mention the name of any [Samvatsaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samvatsara)

This [link](https://sites.google.com/site/harshalarajesh/the-mahabharat-chronology) which describes Mahabharata timeline mentions Samvatsaras but does not give the chapter and verse number, so I couldn't verify it.

Please cite Chapter and Verse number in your answer.